# Visual Studio NuGet Cannot Restore Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, lucene, nuget

I have a large project that has about a dozen dependencies. I have tried to install them all but ran into an error from VS. I am using Visual Studio 2015

"An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find version '3.0.3.1' of package'Lucene.Net.Core'."

Now I have a solution which I can use that is by the same name as this package, but VS refuses to let me updates, remove, or change ANYTHING related to these packages and asks that I restore the packages. I am entirely lost here friends, what should I do?

P.S. the two sources I am using for my package sources are:

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/

The same error occurs for Lucene.Net.Contrib, pstsdk.net, and various packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was not able to get any of the posted answers to work, I ended up removing the project entirely and reinstalling VS, my project, and its dependencies. This ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check for is if your project is built on a version of the NET framework that is less than or equal to the target framework the package has.

If your project is a NET 4.5 based project, but the nuget package has a NET 4.5.2... then the package manager will error out.

Comment: This would not explain why it is that the other packages have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> "An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find version '3.0.3.1' of package'Lucene.Net.Core'."

When I use the packages sources which you provided, I found that **only two versions (4.8.0 & 4.9.0) of package"Lucene.Net.Core"** not have the version '3.0.3.1'.

**Pay Attention:**

I noticed that **the author of this package have updated this package at March 11, 2017(3/11/2017), and only release the version 4.8.0 & 4.9.0**. So this must be the reason for NuGet restore failed.

[image]

Besides, you said:

> I have a solution which I can use that is by the same name as this
>   package, but VS refuses to let me updates, remove, or change ANYTHING
>   related to these packages

If you want to remove those error packages, you can try to use below command to force uninstall those packages:

```
Uninstall-Package Lucene.Net.Core -Force
```

Or you can delete this package from the package folder and delete the package list from the package.config.

Then install the correct version of the packages.

Comment: If you still have error occurs for Lucene.Net.Contrib, pstsdk.net and you can not resolve them, you can provide the error messages for those packages, or provide the package info in the package.config, I will keep follow.

Comment: Thanks, I will try what you said above, but I thought I would also mention they are the same errors for pstsdk.net and Lucene.Net.Contrib

Comment: When I try to run this I get the error "Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph."

Comment: @KurtPrice, just as I said in the comment, the error should not be exactly the same. You can find the dependency of Lucene.Net.Contrib is Lucene.Net. This package also updated by the author at May 22, 2017. But I could not make sure this is the reason for installation fail without detail info. And I could not found the package pstsdk.net, this may be custom package, you need to confirm it with project developer.

Comment: Did you get that error when you uninstall the package with option "-force"? Have you try to the another way? Delete that package from the package folder, delete that package info from package.config and project file, then re-install that package. If you don not know how to do those steps, please let me for free, I will give you a detail info step by step. Hope you can resolve you question.

Comment: Yes, I still got the error with -force. I ended up just removing the entire project and starting over, which has worked.

Answer (score -1):

Another thing to check is that the package manager configuration settings in visual studio list the public nuget feed (and if the feed is enabled too).